# Game loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-loop, fixed-timestep

I've been into javascript game programming with html5 and canvas lately. So far I've only been able to implement a game loop with setInterval, but I'm aware this means using fixed timestep. I've always used game engines with the "delta time" approach, I'm sorry I can't recall how that timestep was called. But anyway, I had several questions.

- How could I implement a game loop with the delta time approach?
- Will I get benefit from it in any particular way?

Also any information you point out related to that is welcome.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but for you it might be easier to find a [javascript HTML5 engine](http://html5gameengine.com/) where this is all taken care of.

Comment: Well as I'm not doing this professionally but for the purpose of learning how to do it, I'm still interested. Although it's a nice advice, I'll take a look to some of those engines too

Comment: Reading other people's source code can be an excellent way to learn things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have three ways to periodically invoke some code.

- have a infinite loop with sleeps.
- use setIntervall to perodically be waken
- use requestAnimationFrame for when the browser is idle

Although this is about animation, it covers the basic crux of the problem: [Animating In Code Using JavaScript](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_in_code_using_javascript.htm)